# using Polymer with jQuery Mobile, works in Chrome, JQM events not firing elsewhere

Tags: jquery-mobile, polymer

In this example,
http://jsfiddle.net/7Ev43/2/ the inclusion of the first `<script>` line (`<script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/platform.js"></script>`) causes the jQueryMobile events `pagebeforecreate` and `pageinit` events not to fire, in Safari and Firefox. However, it works in Chrome.

Any ideas on how to amend this?

**Further investigation:**

It appears that on Firefox and Safari, `platform.js` is overriding `addEventListener`
At this point I'm not sure how to proceed further, any suggestions would be most welcome.

---

full example:

```
<!DOCTYPE >
<html>
<head>

    <script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/platform.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>




<script>





$(document).on('mobileinit', '#mainpage', function(){
    console.log("mobileinit");
})

$(document).delegate("#mainpage", "pagebeforecreate", function(){
    console.log("pagebeforecreate")

})

$(document).on("pageinit", '#mainpage', function()
{
    console.log("pageinit")
});




console.log('end of script')
</script>



</head>




<body>

    <div id="mainpage" data-role="page" data-theme="b">
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```